# Should I say I have a Bachelor Degree when actually my degree is another one?

Tags: resume, ethics, education, europe

In my country, there are two kinds of undergraduate degrees (Bachelors and Technologic). My degree is currently the latter one, but it is basically the same curriculum of a Bachelor in Computer Science, the only difference being basically that the course is little bit shorter (Computer Science is around 4 years part time, and mine is 3 years part time) mostly because we focus a little less on the math side.

Is it unethical/wrong to say I have a Bachelor Degree when applying **in other countries that doesn't have this kind of degree (Technologic)?** I'm focusing here mostly on the European market, but I don't think this is related to any region at all.

Comment: Why would you switch it? If I was reviewing a resume that had a degree I had never heard of, I would spend time googling it and ultimately likely spend more time reviewing your application.

Comment: Is a "_Technologic degree_" 2-years if done full-time?  I'm having trouble finding information about it online, though the first LinkedIn profile I saw with someone who claims such a degree apparently completed it in 1 year.

Comment: It might help to state what your country is for the benefit of those trying to figure out what this degree is.

Comment: Are you sure that degree is an actual academic degree? Some schools will provide you with a degree but it doesn't have any academic value.

Comment: I’m a little concerned about the “part time.” A degree that takes four years part time would be more equivalent to an Associates degree here in the US. A Bachelors degree is four years, full time.

Comment: Post-secondary vocational degrees of some European countries are legally equivalent to academic bachelor and master degrees in all countries participating in the [Bologna Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bologna_agreement).

Comment: @ernst-friedman-hill note that Czech primary+secondary education is 9+4 years, which is 1 year more than in the US. Bachelor's is then 3 years and master's additional 2 years. At the end of the day, formally, education level is determined by time spent in education. It follows that a 3-year part-time course cannot be recognised as a 3-year full-time course.

Comment: Standard public education here is kindergarten plus 1-12 grades — 13 years.

Comment: @Josef - U.S. through secondary education is 13 years as well. We have a grade before 1st grade (kindergarten). So 12th grade is your 13th year of schooling in the U.S. It's directly comparing a 3 year part-time to a 4 year full-time. Definitely not right at all in the U.S.

Comment: @bryangrezeszak I believe that the last year of kindergarten being preparation for school is universal. Perhaps another point of view will make it more clear: on average, Americans finish secondary education one year younger.

Comment: From the username of the OP, I assume this is Eastern Europe - the terms we are looking at is Bachelor Degree (so called "licencjat", at least in Poland), and Engineering Degree (this gives you the title of an engineer, it is NOT synonymous with other degrees - but it can be done in one go. If you are studying in a "technical" field, your offcial title after completing your Masters would be "mgr. inż." - master engineer, or just "inż" if no masters was completed). Both Bachelor and Engineering degree take 3,5 years full time and both areconsidered to be the same level of education.

Comment: @Yuropoor That is specific to Poland. The OP is more likely Czech and it is a bit different there. (And it is *Central* Europe.) Czech Technical Universities issue the same Bc. degree as normal Universities. The Technical Universities then issue the Ing. degree, and that is equivalent to a Master (although it sounds better to ordinary people). However there are also other types of higher education which issue a different non-university degree DiS. similar to an associate degree in other countries https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associate_degree#Europe.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

**It would be deceptive to list your degree as a Bachelors when it isn't a Bachelors.**

If you're showing your studies on a CV, and you're afraid that people from other regions will not know what a "Technologic" degree is, then it would be more reasonable (and correct) to **explain instead of lying.**

For instance, you could list the following on your resume:

> Technologic degree in Computer Science, 2016, University of SuchandSuch
>
> 3 Year program consisting of study in X, Y, Z
>
> GPA of 3.5, Graduated with Honors

This way, you're not lying, but you are explaining the degree to people who may not understand it. Also, **you're not passing on your own judgement of what's equivalent, you're giving them the info and letting them decide** (because, some people may not agree with your interpretation that a 3 year degree is equivalent to a 4 year degree.)

To expand on what Draken mentioned in a comment, If there is a generally accepted framework that equates degrees from your country to those in other countries, it may make sense to list that as well: For instance,

> Technologic degree in Computer Science, 2016, University of SuchandSuch
>
> 3 Year program consisting of study in X, Y, Z
>
> GPA of 3.5, Graduated with Honors
>
> European Qualifications Framework level 5

Comment: As someone who has never heard of a Technologic degree before seeing this question.  If I saw this explanation on the resume I would have a sufficient grasp of what it is to properly evaluate them.

Answer (score 73):

> Is it unethical/wrong to say I have a Bachelor Degree when applying in other countries that doesn't have this kind of degree (Technologic)?

Yes it is. It's simply wrong.

In some European countries, lying on your resume like that may be grounds for firing you for cause, even when they find out 20 years later and it made no difference. Especially Germans are really skilled in screwing you over paperwork (Disclaimer: I know because I am from Germany). Better to get it right from the start.

What you need to do is to put your actual title and then add something like "(roughly equivalent to a Bachelor in $Country)".

Comment: Just to add, some will ask for a local evaluation report (like ECE in US). Uni/mployer hires ECE, then ECE asks for copies of your degrees and then they evaluate them and finally send the evaluation (local equivalence) to the uni/employer. You would get screwed if the evaluation is different than your resume.

Comment: A [disclaimer](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/disclaimer) is not appropriate here. Perhaps this could be rephrased `My home country of Germany is especially skilled ...`

Comment: In many countries, not just in Europe, making a false statement in a resume or CV when applying for a job can be considered fraud, a criminal offence, and can lead to a prison sentence. Really.

Comment: That can mean prison even if you didn't get the job.

Comment: @naiad: It's not a disclaimer, it's a source

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit literal meaning isn't as important as you think it is. there are other things to life

Comment: @naiad Not apple much banana there, I'd say. I hope you don't university that I'm a bit liberal with the meaning fruit ;)

Comment: @naiad: You made a claim. The claim was false. I pointed out that the claim is false. That's a heck of a time to decide that making claims doesn't matter :)

Comment: a disclaimer is appropriate here

Answer (score 6):

Yes you should report your actual degree.  To not do so is fraud.

Just because it is a term they might not know is not a reason the change.  Let them have the chance to ask you or look it up.

If you use Bachelor to give the impression of a 4 year degree and they look at your resume and discover it is 3 year degree and you did not accurately report the degree you will be immediately eliminated as a candidate.

Comment: I like this *Let them have the chance to ask you*.

Answer (score 6):

If you mean DiS ("diplommed specialist") then it is very wrong and lying. It is simply not on the same level in our country, it is not university education, although it is tertiary education roughly on the bachelor level.

Whatever you exactly have, your diploma should say which EQF level it is. If your diploma says it is actually EQF 6, tell that instead. EQF levels are described by [European Qualifications Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Qualifications_Framework). If it is the same EQF level as a bachelor, tell that.

Answer (score 4):

Translating degrees is a major topic. Turn to a good translator, ask your question on a forum for translators or search for official translations for example on university websites.

Btw, bachelor study normally takes 3 years in the EU (acc. to the Bologna process). I would think the key here is whether you can start an M.A./M.Sc. study after getting your "technological" degree, not the duration of study. If you can continue to an M.A./M.Sc. without taking additional courses or similar, your degree is equivalent to an B.A./B.Sc., if not, it's not and you shouldn't describe it as such.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it unethical/wrong to say I have a Bachelor Degree when applying in other countries that doesn't have this kind of degree (Technologic)?

Generally speaking, **including information that is not 100% true in your resume is not recommended.**

In this situations, it is better to be as truthful as possible, while including only the relevant and pertaining information for your application.

I suggest you specify your have Technologic degree, but mention it basically equivalent to a Bachelor's one. Give some detail so anybody that is unaware of such degree can understand what it is about.

Comment: But if a Technologic degree takes 3 years, and a Bachelor's degree takes four years, then they are _not_ basically equivalent.

Comment: Yeah, depends how it is phrased etc

Answer (score 1):

Get an official translation, preferably by the issuing university. Your university also may offer an [international supplement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diploma_Supplement). Either can include a remark such as such as "internationally, the Technologic degree is usually interpreted as bachelor".

Further the supplement includes an explanation of the grading scheme which is essential for someone to review your degree.

Comment: If there is something wrong with the answer, I'd appreciate a comment.

Comment: The problem would be that if you got a degree in Italy for example, and there is no degree available in Germany that matches exactly (they might have one degree that is easier and one that is harder to achieve than your Italian degree), then "official translation" is meaningless. In German, a word correctly naming your degree would simply not exist.

Comment: The question implies that the degree is equivalent to a bachelor. If no equivalent is available, a supplement greatly helps someone who doesn't know the degree to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

In US there are private companies licensed by Department of Education to perform foreign diploma evaluation. You bring your original diploma to them, pay the fee and they translate it and determine what it is equivalent to in US education system and how many college credits you have.

I think something similar has to exist in most countries. In my opinion this is your best bet even if it costs you money. Just make sure that the company you pick for this is actually licensed by local Department of Education. Often hiring companies can provide you with a list of diploma evaluation companies they trust.