# How to specify my foreign degree in my resume?

Tags: resume, united-states, france

I'm actually writing my resume to apply in California. I'm French and I don't know how to translate my study.

I studied for 2 years at a French university (2ème année de Licence Maths/Physique-Chimie/Informatique)

Then, I went to a private computer science school (sandwich course) for 2 years again (Titre niveau 2 (bac +4) de Concepteur développeur informatique inscrit au RNCP). In total, I did 4 years after my high school diploma

Should I write :

- 4 years of university study in software engineering
- Bachelor's Degree (Bachelor Degree?)
- Master's Degree (Master Degree?)

Comment: Can you add the name of the study in French?

Comment: Related, possible duplicates: "[Having a degree in a non-english country, should I translate it to english in the cv?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10416/having-a-degree-in-a-non-english-country-should-i-translate-it-to-english-in-th)" and "[Should I say I have a Bachelor Degree when actually my degree is another one?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/112497/should-i-say-i-have-a-bachelor-degree-when-actually-my-degree-is-another-one)"

Comment: Does the school you received your last degree from have an way that it would translate your degree? I have a FM (Filosofian maisteri) that is reported as an Master's Degree by the university if you request records in English.  Not that you would likely be called on it but if anyone checked you would not want the degree reported by the university to be different.

Comment: Are you applying for a job in industry or academia? Industry may accept an approximate conversion, academia would be much more strict.

Comment: My school dont translate my degree

Comment: Ben Mz, I want to apply in different company such as Google, Microsoft, Twitter...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found this [blog](http://emploiestaca.over-blog.com/article-6978712.html) which state :

*BAC+2 (Licence Maths/Physique-Chimie/Informatique) :* In France it is a [DUT](http://www.onisep.fr/Choisir-mes-etudes/Apres-le-bac/Organisation-des-etudes-superieures/Les-DUT-diplomes-universitaires-de-technologie) but there is no correspondence in the US, you can write : "2 years technical degree in..."

*BAC+4 (Alternance) :* It is a "Maîtrise" **BUT** not a "Master" in France, so you can't say you have a Master Degree. The closest is **Bachelor's Degree** which is a 4 year university course.

The important part when translating from French diploma to every other country is to take the BAC+X denomination or the "Licence" name or the BTS.

**Conclusion :** I would add the two following lines to explain :

> School name (city - Country) - 2 years technical degree in Mathematics, Physics, Chemistry, Computer Science
>
> School name (city - Country) - Bachelor's Degree (4 year course) in Computer Science

If you lack space, you can skip the first line as it does not match a proper degree in the US.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but a "Maîtrise" in France is a "BAC+4", such as my study. Then, are you sure that I should write "Bachelor's Degree" on my resume?

Comment: You are right, "maîtrise" and "master" are 2 different things, i always assumed that was the same thing (as master is "maîtrise" in english...) As stated in the blog I posted, "Maîtrise" is equivalent to four university year then a Bachelor.

Comment: “Bachelor's Degree which is a 4 year university course” — where? this is highly location dependent. In many places it’s three years.

Comment: The information used are specific from France to the USA... I could not find more precisely about California.

Comment: Then you advise me to write something like "School name (city) - Bachelor's Degree (4 year university course) " ?

Comment: I have added some information on my answer. But basically yes this is the kind of line I would put. Don't forget to mention the country next to the city. For example, i'm in Lyon and there is a Lyon city in the US... As strange as it is

Comment: I'm not sure this is answer is completly correct. If you did 2 years of licence, it is not equivalent to a DUT at all. This comes from the simple fact that, after a 2 years DUT, you actually gradute, which you don't if you do 2 years of licence (instead of 3). Also, is your diploma a Bac+4 or a Bac+2. It is not because you graduated 4 years after the Bac that you have a Bac+4 diploma (e.g. 2 Bac+4 diplomas are not equivalent to a PhD)

Comment: I investigated a bit further, and it seems that your diploma is a Bac+4 in 2 years (e.g. after a Bac+2). Hence, to me, you should mention only your diploma as a 4 year diploma, similar to @Valrog's answer. However, you should make clear that after your 2 years of licence, you did not graduate. For instance, you can add the years (e.g. 2014 - 2016 - 2 years of university ; 2016 - 2018 - Bachelor Degree (4 years course) at SCHOOLNAME.)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using https://www.wes.org or  https://www.ece.org/ECE or one of their competitors, and then using whatever they say the equivalent credential is.

Degrees and certifications are mainly a way to get past HR, they aren't why you get the job.  The goal of a CV/resume is to get an interview, which is where you convince them you are the best person for the job.  Mainly in ways that aren't directly related to your paperwork.